PL/SQL Function not working with TYPE as RECORD
My business requirement is to create a function that returns a select statement. I created a function successfully with the database type. However, now the requirement is to replace database type with record type and after doing so my function is now giving the error "PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:     begin function pragma procedure "
Below is the code that works fine:
create or replace type type_TRAUDIT040 as object
   (X VARCHAR2(1000), 
    DOCUMENT_ID VARCHAR2(1000 ), 
    PR3_ID VARCHAR2(1000 ), 
    MICROFILM_ID VARCHAR2(1000 ), 
    CNT_PR3_ID VARCHAR2(1000 ), 
    CNT_MICRO_ID VARCHAR2(1000 ), 
    CREATE_USERID VARCHAR2(1000 ), 
    PAYEE_PRVR_EXT_ID VARCHAR2(1000 ), 
    RECCNT VARCHAR2(1000 ),
    cp_claim_types_desc VARCHAR2(1000 ),
    cp_claim_status_desc VARCHAR2(1000 ),
    count_document_id  VARCHAR2(1000 )
   );
   
   create or replace type table_TRAUDIT040 is table of type_TRAUDIT040;


create or replace function fn_traudit040
(
    p_Ambulance  varchar2
    ) 
    return table_TRAUDIT040
    as test_type table_TRAUDIT040;
   
BEGIN

     SELECT type_TRAUDIT040( 
             x,document_id,PR3_ID,MICROFILM_ID,CNT_PR3_ID,CNT_MICRO_ID,create_userid,PAYEE_PRVR_EXT_ID,RecCnt,'1' ,'2','3'
           )
    BULK COLLECT INTO test_type
    FROM   TRAUDIT040;
     
    RETURN test_type;

END;

Now when I replace Database type with record type, my code stops working. Can someone guide me what's wrong in the below code:
create procedure p_traudit040(p_name varchar2)
is

    TYPE type_rec_summary IS RECORD (
        bhs_id  VARCHAR2(40),        
        Name    VARCHAR2(40),
        bh_inst_id  NUMBER
    );
    
    TYPE type_tab_sum IS
        TABLE OF type_rec_summary;


 
    FUNCTION f_get_data return type_tab_sum
    as test_type type_tab_sum ;
    begin
    
         SELECT type_rec_summary( 
             bhs_id, Name, bh_inst_id
           )
    BULK COLLECT INTO test_type
    FROM   blu_benefit_holder_sections  tr040
    where Name = p_name;
    
    return test_type;
end;

Below is the error screenshot:

Many thanks in advance.

Your structure of procedure and function definition is wrong:
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE p_traudit040(p_name VARCHAR2)
IS
   -- Define record type
   TYPE type_rec_summary IS RECORD (
      bhs_id      VARCHAR2(40),        
      name        VARCHAR2(40),
      bh_inst_id  NUMBER
   );
   
   -- Define a table type of records
   TYPE type_tab_sum IS
      TABLE OF type_rec_summary;
      
   -- Function to get data
   FUNCTION f_get_data(p_name_in VARCHAR2) RETURN type_tab_sum
   IS
      test_type type_tab_sum;
   BEGIN
      SELECT type_rec_summary( 
               bhs_id, 
               name, 
               bh_inst_id
             )
      BULK COLLECT INTO test_type
      FROM   blu_benefit_holder_sections tr040
      WHERE  name = p_name_in;

      RETURN test_type;
   END f_get_data;

BEGIN
   -- You can call the function `f_get_data` inside the procedure's main body.
   DECLARE
      data_summary type_tab_sum;
   BEGIN
      data_summary := f_get_data(p_name);
      
      -- You can now process the data_summary or other staff here
      FOR i IN 1..data_summary.COUNT LOOP
         dbms_output.put_line('bhs_id: ' || data_summary(i).bhs_id || ', Name: ' || data_summary(i).name || ', bh_inst_id: ' || data_summary(i).bh_inst_id);
      END LOOP;
   END;
END p_traudit040;
/


My requirement is to return a select statement and that's why your solution will not work for me. I guess in this case I have to create a function only and not a procedure. But i am not sure how to use record type in a function and return a select statement which is set of rows and columns

Or maybe you can generate the select statement as string and then execute this select statement as a dynamic query with execute immediate clause at where  you are calling the function.

I want to create a function similar to my above mentioned function  fn_traudit040 but with record type.
